# Azure Cognitive Service - Text to Speech : Text Limit

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I have created an Azure Cognitive services for Text to Speech. With the guidelines given in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-text-to-speech?tabs=streaming), I was able to get it working.

Query on the character/word limit that is unclear is

I am using a Standard Pricing Tier for this. So the question is ,is there a limit on the no. of characters per request that it expects.
One of the point mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-text-to-speech?tabs=streaming#sample-request-1) is,

> If the body length is long, and the resulting audio exceeds 10
> minutes, it's truncated to 10 minutes. In other words, the audio
> length can't exceed 10 minutes”

Below is the audio content that I am trying to convert to audio. **The character for which is 1121,words is 193** which I believe should be less that 10mins & Even if that is the case ,the audio should be truncated but here the response says 200 OK but no audio is generated in response as highlighted in the image herewith.

[image]

```
<speak version='1.0' xml:lang='en-US'><voice xml:lang='en-US' xml:gender='Male'
name='en-US-ChristopherNeural'>
```

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and **I**.

```
</voice></speak>
```

Her's the header parameters as well
[image]

Could someone point me in the right direction on why the audio response for the above text is not getting generated unless I remove characters .**In this case removing any further characters after and.**

Any input is appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the issue and faced the same issue. The reason behind it is the limitation clearly stated in the official documentation.

[image]

I have created Azure Cognitive Service and it does not have more than above mentioned pricing tiers.
Whatever the pricing tier, the maximum limit is 10min.

[image]

Whatever the mechanism we consider like Python SDK or direct portal, the same mechanism will be applying.